# can git pull support continue download?

Tags: linux, git, git-pull

I am using git to update the nios2 for linux archive packages, but network is really very much slow, I am boring with that when the connection broken unexpectedly,I had to restart the work, it cost too much time, so I wondered that can git pull continue download source tree from last break point?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the fact that git clone can't be restarted, I doubt pull will be able to either. You'll have to use git reset to get back to where you started.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean that git clone or pull get a broken source(not finish the download), so how can I merge the broken data, will it break my old archive?

Comment: You can't merge in the broken data, you'll have to do the download again. You could try using the diff logs to fix it manually , but that may cause other problems